# Javascript Image loading Facebook style

Tags: javascript, facebook, image, load

so I was browsing through this page: http://360langstrasse.sf.tv/
It basically is a Javascript-Street View, but only allowing one direction. Therefore its kinda like playing a movie.
When moving fast I notived that the images are grainy/pixelated, the same way as when browsing through Facebook.

I was wondering how to implement this?
I tried with sending small base64 encoded images in the markup, and then draw it on a canvas until the 'real' image was loaded.

This worked fine, but left me thinking if this would indeed increase performance, or do sites like facebook do it differently?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards Jens

Edit: Or do they only display the images differently? Have another render process than usual?
As I don't see any small images beeing loaded?

Edit 2: The below mentionewd option to load small images first is descriped nicely here: http://www.phpied.com/picassa-progressive-image-rendering/
But basically it is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose caching (having in-page) bad-resolution images and fetching better is a real way to accomplish this.

The other way would be linking to small images in a normal way, and fetching bigger with JS - small images should load really fast, or you can subscribe to their load event (tricky in IE) and show the page (remove some overlay) once they are loaded.

BTW, instead of using canvas you can put base64 directly into `src`

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,...
```

Comment: Thats the way I thought of too, loading small images and when stopped on a single image load the bigger one, but at least on the link above I don't see any thubmnail images beeing loaded. I'll check this on facebook if they load small images first. Thanks for the base64 tip.

Comment: I also thought this effect could be achieved with proper img format like JPEG2000 (though this particular format is not widely supported by browsers)

Comment: As you said the JPEG2000 isn't widely spread, but got me thinking if they used a technology called progressive decoding. I'll see to try to get any imformation if facebook does this and how they do it in browser or javascript.

Comment: yes, progressive decoding is what I meant when speaking about JPEG2000.

Comment: I figured, the question remaining to me is how to do this with regular JPEGs in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Progressive JPEG's!
One create such with imagemagick for example. This way the browser renders progressively until aborted or completed. Those images may be bigger than normal images, but not always.
Furthermore they provide the ability to be seen before completely downloaded.

Thanks for the help!